# What is the read/write equivalent of serializers.StringRelatedField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework 3, I want to return the unicode value of a pk relationship, the way you can using a serializer.StringRelatedField, but I need the value to be writable, too. StringRelatedField is read only.

I don't care if the API accepts the pk, or the string value, on the PUT (though accepting the string would be nifty, and would save me grabbing all the pks!). The API just needs to return the unicode string value on the GET.

I'm thinking PrimaryKeyRelatedField might be the way to go, but what does the query look like?

For instance, if the model I want is "Model", and I want Model.name to be serialized, what does this command look like:

```
name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Model.objects.get(pk=????))
```

I'm struggling because I don't know how to get the pk from the serializer object in order to query the related model ...

That's presuming PrimaryKeyRelatedField is what I need, of course. Which may be totally wrong.

Thanks

John

Here are example models as requested, slightly changed for clarity:

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Car(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  make = models.ForeignKey(CarMake)
  car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel)

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   car_model = serializers.StringRelatedField() //like this, but read/write

   class Meta:
   model = Car
```

In this example I'm serializing Car, trying to return a string value of CarModel that can be updated with a select dropdown in a form.
If I use different serializers, one for POST that expects the PK and one for everything else that returns the string, the select directive in the form gets very messy.

So, ideally, I just want to be able to POST the string value, and have the API complete the lookup and save the string as a PK.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your model as well?

Comment: Added it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I just want to be able to POST the string value, and have the API complete the lookup and save the string as a PK."

That would imply that 'name' should be unique. If it isn't unique then the lookup might return several instances. In the example you currently have 'name' isn't unique, but if it was then you could use...

```
car_model = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=..., lookup_field='name')
```

I'm not convinced if that's actually what you want though. The best way to clarify these sorts of questions is typically to forget about the code for a moment, and just focus on a precise description of what you want the input and output representations to look like?...

Comment: yes, sorry, name is unique. I want to return CarModel.name in the serializer, rather than CarModel.pk or CarModel.slug, so I can use the value to populate a select widget. I can do it read-only with StringRelatedField, but then I can't POST to the API with the CarModel.name selected by the user.

Comment: To put this context, it's part of an effort to do away with nested serializers, which were getting messy. I'm trying to write a single, neat serializer that doesn't nest other serializers and works with multiple ReST verbs and doesn't require a second GET from the client to look up the string value of the PK. But I'm new to ReST and I'm not even sure if such a goal is best practice. Maybe you should always return PKs in the API and expect the client to do a second db call to look up the string value?

Comment: It just dawned on me, SlugRelatedField with "slug_field='name'' could be the very thing I am looking for. Sorry to be so slow.

Comment: @John Usually for the queryset you can just do `Model.objects.all()`. The `queryset` argument determines what the possible choices for writing (not reading) are, I believe.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I can just use `serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name')` with no queryset and my problems are over, no?

Comment: Oh bum. Needs a queryset if it's not to be readonly. i figured Model.objects.all() would return the whole table, but I see you are right. It just returns the lookup value. I am very close now!

Comment: this worked, just as Kevin and Tom said: `car_model = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=CarModel.objects.all(), slug_field='name')`. Thanks guys!