# django rest framework - username field not rendering in browsable api html form

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The Django Rest Framework is not displaying `username` field in my browsable api html form but when I comment down the username in below code it is showing username field in my browsable api html form. I am new to Django so anyone can please help me here

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Note

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='note-detail', lookup_field='pk')
    #username = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'username', 'note_text', 'created_date', 'updated_date']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`StringRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) is used to denote relations where the target result is computed using the `__str__` method. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/95d4843abeecea96754a147f4f2cca33e620ad09/rest_framework/relations.py#L231), you will notice that a `StringRelatedField` is just read only. Since the value cannot be edited, you don't see it in the browsable API HTML form.

Once you comment that line, the foreignkey relationship is used and it returns the id of the user. In that case, you do see the field `username` in the form but the value is not a string but an integer.

I don't think there is a way to make a `StringRelatedField` editable in the form. For more information please have a look at the relates [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689281/what-is-the-read-write-equivalent-of-serializers-stringrelatedfield).

Answer (score 0):

The [model serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) will *automatically generate a set of fields for you based on the model*.